# sed remove specific key with varying value from string

Tags: string, sed, trim

Say I have a string:

```
ap=test:::bc=exam:::dc=comic:::mp=calc:::
```

Read in a linux box, i need to remove say `bc=exam`, the key is always the same, but the value can be any value, string or digits, and the placement of the key value pair can be anywhere in the string.

i've got to

```
sed -e 's/:::bc=\(.*:::\)*/\1/'
```

which only removes the key and a delimiter.

or

```
sed -e 's/:::bc=.*\(:::\)*/\1/'
```

which is removing everything from the key on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about matching anything up until a `:` when matching the value of they key?

Comment: `sed  's/:::bc=[^:]*//' file` ([demo](https://ideone.com/hb1vYD))?

Comment: Can a value contain a colon?

Comment: no semi colons in the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your values do not contain semicolons, you may match them with a negated bracket expression, `[^:]*`:

```
sed  's/:::bc=[^:]*//' file
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/hb1vYD).

The `:::bc=[^:]*` matches `:::bc` and then any 0+ chars other than a colon.

Comment: Wiktor. Thanks! that works great. another question is... what if the delimiters use characters that need to be escaped? for instance ^M. if i replace the delimiters with ^M, it leaves the value.

Comment: `ap=test^Mbc^Mexam^Mdc=comic^Mmp=calc^M`, they are not carriage returns, they were, but there is a conversion another app does, that I can't avoid (old legacy app)

Comment: @cmct90025 It looks like `^M` is used as the delimiter and the "equals" sign. If the value cannot contain a `^` char, you may use a similar trick: `sed 's/\^Mbc\^M[^^]*//' file`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/TTUIxQ). Else, you will need a multiple step approach, or use Perl, `perl -pe 's/\^Mbc\^M.*?(?=\^M|$)//' file`.